# Isolating Decimals

Tags: divisibility, decimal-expansion

I'm in need of isolating the decimal part of a number using maths only, no excel functions or anything like that, but it's proving to be much harder than I thought it would be.

For example, I have the number "XXX.YY" and I want to just have the "YY" part. How would I possibly go about this? I know in Excel I can do "MOD(XXX.YY,1)" but is there anyway of actually doing this with just math?

Comment: $(XXX.YY-XXX)*100$?..What do you need it for?

Comment: $x-INT(x)$ may be or $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what "XXX" is, so cannot subtract it. I require it for an application in which only whole numbers are allowed to be transmitted. So i need to deconstruct the decimal part, times by 100, then later divide by 100 and add it back on.

Comment: x-floor(x)? @SilverShotBee. As said in previous comments.

Comment: I think it should be moved to Computer Science portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your number $XXX.YY$ be equal to $Z$.

Then the decimal portion of your number is given by $Z - \lfloor{Z}\rfloor$, where $\lfloor{Z}\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $Z$.

Comment: Note that people who need this a lot often denote it $\{x\}\mathrel{:=} x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ (of course, they mention this notation in the preliminaries because it's considered non-standard).

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks!